# Is it possible to filter the selectable days in the Kendo UI datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

Does anyone know if it is possible to pass in an array of days to limit the days that are selectable in the Kendo UI datepicker?

Eg - to make only Mon-Fri selectable..

```
<input kendo-date-picker=""    
       ng-model="dateString"
       days="[0,1,2,3,4]"/>
```

Comment: I don't think there's such a feature for the datepicker. Maybe binding a JS function to the `Change` event of the datepicker and check there if it is a week or weekend day. If it's a weekend day, `e.preventDefault();` should avoid the selection

Comment: @chiapa Thanks but I was hoping to have the day greyed out and readonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such functionality for the Kendo DatePicker: it [has been asked in the Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/deactivating-dates-in-datepicker) before and the answer from them is "the behaviour is not currently supported".

There is a [UserVoice](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2758914-disable-dates-in-the-calendar) item that is requesting it to be created.

Here's a custom workaround that simulates what you intend:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var p = $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    value: new Date(), //setting the value to "today"
    open: function(e) {
      $(".disabledDay").parent().removeClass("k-link");
      $(".disabledDay").parent().removeAttr("href");
      $('.k-weekend a').bind('click', function() {
        return false;
      });
    }
  }).data("kendoDatePicker");
});
```

```css
.k-weekend {
  background-color: silver;
}
.k-weekend:hover {
  background-color: silver !important;
}
.k-weekend a:hover {
  background-color: silver !important;
}
.k-calendar a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>KendoUI Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="datepicker" style="width:150px;" />

</body>

</html>
```

That's not ideal, I know, but since the feature doesn't exist in the widget itself, only through workarounds we can obtain such a behaviour. With this, you can't select weekend days and with a little tweek on the CSS you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. Agree its not ideal but its better than nothing. Will accept your answer.